# Count all values Firebase Java API

Tags: java, android, count, firebase

I'm trying to count all the values in my firebase database in Java. But its not working, I have looked at some tutorials for this but haven't found any for Java programmers.

Here is my database:

```
Language
  German
    Message
      -Jf6ShYy7niHrqg_x4Tc: "Tomorrow is very windy"
      -Jf9v0xHAxINUUANrORU: "Today is very windy and rainy"
```

Here is my code, note the line I attempted to use count max value:

```
    Firebase f = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/Language/German/Message/");             
    f.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            disp_msg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display_msg);
            //disp_msg.setText(snapshot.getValue().toString());
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> ds = snapshot.getChildren();
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> ids = ds.iterator();
            Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) ids.next().getValue();
            String msg = newPost.get("pubMsg").toString();
            disp_msg.setText(msg.toString());

            //The line below does not work getting the maximum values
            int maxValueInMap=(Collections.max(newPost.values().toString())); 

        }
```

This is the error I get at the max function from Collections:

> The method max(Collection) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem in Java, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working while inside my firebase child directory, found the firebase function:

```
            long maxNum = snapshot.getChildrenCount();
            int nums = (int)maxNum;
            disp_msg.setText(msg.toString() + Integer.toString(nums));
```

Answer (score 0):

IT should be:

```
int maxValueInMap=(Collections.max(newPost.values()));
```

You accidentally did `.toString`. A String is not a `Collection`, and therefore `.max` will not work on it.

I might recommend however, seeing if you can do an order by with limit clause, as it could get expensive to run `Collections.max` again and again. I can't see a `TOP` function in the firebase docs, but this would be even better.